# Modular document: separate BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing

I am building a modular LaTeX document for an econ journal. Each component of the modular document is one article. I want to have separate BibTeX references for each article.

First, I created a big combined BibTeX. When I compile the whole document, each article's bibliography contains everything from the big combined BibTeX.

Then I tried to split the big BibTeX file into separate ones for each article. When I did that, the complier made the first article's bibliography the bibliography for all of the articles.

What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: `biber` and `biblatex`, I suspect, is the way to go. Highly configurable at whatever logical level you desire.

Comment: Have a look at the [possible packages](http://www.ctan.org/topic/bibtex-multi) that can help to setup several bibliographies in one document.

Comment: Hello in here! Since you ask, _what should I do_, I suggest you to make a [Minimal (non)-Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), that would (1) compile and (2) show the complete bibliography under each article. Only then we can fully understand your problem and help you.

Answer (score 2):

In a removed comment to an deleted answer [yaleeconjournal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27027/yaleeconjournal) wrote:

> Thanks! I figured it out. I used the chapterbib package and it worked.